# When adding a Search Bar and Search Display Controller to a complex tableHeaderView, The UISearchBar disappears when it gains focus

Tags: swift, ios8, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am using a single ViewController and an associated NIB, no storyboard. I'm ready to pull my hair out.

### The Issue

Notice in the video after focusing, a tiny bit of the field is visible in the top left corner, only to disappear completely after clicking on the shaded area over the UITableView. When going into the view hierarchy, it shows that the searchBar is being moved out of its original hierarchal position.

[This video](https://vid.me/5054)

### The NIB

[Screenshot of the NIB, showing the structure of the tableHeaderView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjDax.png)

### The Code

```
import UIKit 
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, 
UITableViewDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var bigLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var buttonGroupSegment: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet var tableViewHeader: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet var searchBar: UISearchBar!

// MARK: VIEW CONTROLLER
override init() {
    super.init(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: nil)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.initTableView();
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad();
    self.initLabelStyling();
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: TABLE VIEW HEADER
func initTableViewHeader() -> Void{
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.tableViewHeader;

    self.initSearchView();
    self.initSegmentedControl();
}

// MARK: THE SEGMENTED CONTROL
func initSegmentedControl() -> Void{
    let font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 10);
    let color = UIColor.whiteColor();
    let lighterColor = color.colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5);
    self.buttonGroupSegment.tintColor = UIColor.clearColor();
self.buttonGroupSegment.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName : lighterColor, NSFontAttributeName: font!, NSKernAttributeName: 0.7], forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    self.buttonGroupSegment.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName : color, NSFontAttributeName: font!], forState: UIControlState.Selected);

    // Change the case of all the titles
    let c = self.buttonGroupSegment.subviews.count;
    for i in 0..<c{
        if let title = self.buttonGroupSegment.titleForSegmentAtIndex(i){
            self.buttonGroupSegment.setTitle(title.uppercaseString, forSegmentAtIndex: i);
        }
    }

}

// MARK: SEARCH VIEW
func initSearchView() -> Void{
    let searchBar = self.searchDisplayController!.searchBar;
    searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor();
    searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage();
    searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.clearColor();
    searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    let numViews = searchBar.subviews[0].subviews.count;
    var searchField: UITextField?

    for i in 0..<numViews{
        if searchBar.subviews[0].subviews[i].isKindOfClass(UITextField.self) {
            searchField = searchBar.subviews[0].subviews[i] as? UITextField;
        }
    }

    if searchField != nil{

        // Fonts and colors
        let font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 12);
        let textColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
        searchField!.font = font;
        searchField!.textColor = textColor;
        if searchField!.respondsToSelector("setAttributedPlaceholder:"){
            if let placeholder = searchField!.placeholder{
                let placeHolderColor = UIColor(red: 100, green: 100, blue: 100, alpha: 0.5);
                let attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholder, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : placeHolderColor, NSFontAttributeName: font!]);
                searchField!.attributedPlaceholder = attributedPlaceholder;
            }
        }
        searchField!.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 100, green: 100, blue: 100, alpha: 0.2);
        var searchIcon: UIImageView? = searchField?.leftView as? UIImageView;
        searchIcon!.image = searchIcon!.image?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)
        searchIcon?.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor();

        var clearIcon: UIImageView? = searchField?.rightView as? UIImageView;
        if clearIcon != nil{
            clearIcon!.image = clearIcon!.image!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)
            clearIcon!.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
        }
    }

}

// MARK: THE SEARCH VIEW DELEGATE METHODS
func searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch(controller: UISearchDisplayController) {

}

func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String!) -> Bool {
    self.filterContentForSearchText(searchString, scope:"");
    return true;
}

func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: NSString, scope: String) -> Void{
    self.dataFiltered = self.data.filter({(pet: String) -> Bool in
        let stringMatch = pet.rangeOfString(searchText)
        return stringMatch != nil;
    })
}

// MARK: TABLE VIEW
let data = ["Cat","Dog","Bird","Fish","Ferret","Rat","Hamster","Chicken","Goat","Pig","Donkey","Monkey", "Rabbit", "Fox", "Snake", "Frog", "Spider","Rooster","Aligator","Pocupine","Squirrel","Duck","Turtle","Lizard","Lama"];
var dataFiltered: [String] = [];
let cellClass: String = "Cell";

func initTableView() -> Void{
    self.initTableViewHeader();
    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: self.cellClass);


// MARK: TABLE VIEW DELEGATES AND DATA SOURCE METHODS
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView{
        return self.dataFiltered.count
    }else{
        return self.data.count;
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    var cell: UITableViewCell?

    cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellClass) as? UITableViewCell;

    if (cell == nil){
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: self.cellClass)
    }

    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView{
        cell?.textLabel?.text = self.dataFiltered[indexPath.row]
    }else{
        cell?.textLabel?.text = self.data[indexPath.row];
    }

    return cell!;
}

// MARK: STYLE THE LABEL (ADD A LINE)
func initLabelStyling()->Void{
    let v = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bigLabel.frame.width, 1));
    v.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 100, green: 100, blue: 100, alpha: 0.2);
    self.bigLabel.addSubview(v)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Has this been resolved? I know it has something to do with the nav bar in the Navigation Controller being over-layed on top of the search bar. If you run it in simulator for iPhone 6, then turn it to landscape you can see the search bar under the nav bar. Will report back if n when I have a solution!

Edit: There we go, got it!

I added the below (setNavigationBarHidden), there's probably a better place for it but since I am just prototyping that will do for now:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if self.searchDisplayController!.active {
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
        return self.filteredPlayers.count
    } else {
        return self.selectedPlayers.count
    }
}

...

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if self.searchDisplayController!.active {
        self.selectedPlayers.append(self.filteredPlayers[indexPath.row])
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
        self.searchDisplayController!.setActive(false, animated: true)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, adding these two methods did not do the trick, and the search field still "disappears" when it gains focus. I "sort of" fixed this issue by removing the Search Display Controller bit altogether and in its place, just using a vanilla searchBar. Because this solution doesn't answer my original question and is what I consider a workaround, I left the question open.